# The probability that the particle is at the start after three moves?

Tags: probability

In a triangular lattice a particle moves from a lattice point to any of its 6 neighbouring lattice points with equal probability. What is the probability that the particle is back at its starting point after 3 moves?

Should I multiply the probabilities of the particle moving from one point to the other like 1/6*1/6*1/6 , but I feel this is not right as one of the triangle edge would have a different probability.Is this correct?

Comment: Indeed every path made of three consecutive moves has probability $\left(\frac16\right)^3$ (and I fail to get your objection about this) but the main task is to enumerate those that end at the starting point. The first move is irrelevant, given the first move two second moves are possible, given such first and second moves one third move is possible hence the answer is $$\frac66\cdot\frac26\cdot\frac16$$ Note that the numerator $12$ is also twice the number of triangles based on the starting point (and you should try to explain this fact if you want to understand the answer).

Comment: Thank you Did I thought I of just the triangular section instead of considering it as a lattice point half way through solving the problem. I get it now! Thanks a ton!!!!

Comment: @Did shouldn't you have posted this as an answer

Comment: Please do so. $  $